# Quick way to skip line while inserting a csv into postgresql if the 'price' column doesn't have a value?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

Here's a sample of my code, just wondering if it's easy to skip a line on the insert if the 'price' column is blank, and if so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
def insert_data():
  drop_table_if_exists()
  #create table
  cursor.execute("create table IF NOT EXISTS %s (%s);" % (tbl_name, col_str))



  with open(file_path, newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
      print(row)

      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) \
        VALUES (%%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s, %%s)" \
        % (tbl_name, cols), row[:16])
      time.sleep(1)
      #make public
      cursor.execute('''grant select on table %s to public''' % (tbl_name))
      conn.commit()

      print('im in the loop')
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just had to add if all(row). It removes a row if there is any empty columns at all, it doesn't specify which column, but close enough:

```
for row in reader:
      print(row)
      if all(row):
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s (%s) \
```